# How to send response from php server to iphone?

Tags: php, objective-c, http-headers, response

In the server, I am receiving the request, processing it with the database and redirecting to new pages as necessary.But I don't know how to send error msgs to the app if something fails.In the app we use the 'NSHTTPURLResponse Selector statusCode'.

I tried sending responses as status code,

```
header('HTTP Error',true,404); //it works
```

But, I need to know how to use httpresponse or is there any best way to send responses in php?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want is a *webservice*. Just google on it.

Comment: You could echo whatever message you want as HTML, and parse it from NSURLConnection's data property.

Comment: I mean, I'm no php/http/REST/whatever guru, but that works for me. I'm sure there's a more elegant/right way to do it, but...